# binding коллекции к listbox в xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

У меня есть коллекция `public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection`
у класса `MyClass` есть интовое свойство.

Так же есть листбокс, который я хочу заполнить объектами этой коллекции, при нажатии на каждый элемент в текстбоксе должно высвечиваться свойство выбранного элемента, но писать `listBox1.DataSource/ItemsSource = ...` - нельзя, надо делать биндинг только в xaml'e и я никак не разберусь, как это реализовать. коллекция заполнена и инициализирована

Comment: а коллекция MyCollection где заполняется?

Comment: @Stack либо в отдельном классе, например,  class Collections, либо в partial class MainWindow : Window

Comment: _"в partial class MainWindow"_ -- в нем есть такая строка `this.DataContext = new MyCollection();`? если нет, то добаьте. а дальше надо только указать в xaml правильные {Binding ... } у контролов.

Comment: @Stack добавил строчку this.DataContext = new MyCollection();
 а в xaml'е:
     <ListBox x:Name="mylist" Height="215" Width="197" PreviewMouseDown="list_MouseDown1"
                         PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="list_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                         PreviewMouseMove="list_PreviewMouseMove" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"... 
такой биндинг неправильно прописан?

Comment: _ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"_ -- должно быть так {Binding}

Comment: @Stack  а если у меня три коллекции и три листбокса, то как быть? после заполнения каждой коллекции писать this.DataContext = new MyCollection(); (имя будет меняться, конечно), и при просто temsSource="{Binding} они все правильно заполнятся?

Comment: три коллекции объединяют в один класс. коллекции в нем определяют как свойства этого класс. и объект этого класс передается в this.DataContext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно завести свойство выбранного элемента в коллекции (Не забудьте о реализации INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
public MyClass SelectedItem {get; set; }
```

Далее в xaml делаете привязку к этому свойству:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.IntProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**UPDATE**

Приведу код целиком:

```
// модель представления элемента коллекции
public sealed class CollectionItemVm : BaseVm
{
    public int IntProperty
    {
        get { return _intProperty; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _intProperty, value); }
    }
    private int _intProperty;
}

// модель представления главного окна
public sealed class MainVm : BaseVm
{
    public ObservableCollection<CollectionItemVm> MyCollection
    {
        get { return _myCollection ?? (_myCollection = new ObservableCollection<CollectionItemVm>()); }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<CollectionItemVm> _myCollection;

    public CollectionItemVm SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value); }
    }
    private CollectionItemVm _selectedItem;

    public MainVm()
    {
        MyCollection.Add(new CollectionItemVm { IntProperty = 1 });
        MyCollection.Add(new CollectionItemVm { IntProperty = 2 });

        SelectedItem = MyCollection.Last();
    }
}

// представление главного окна
<Window ...
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4.ViewModels">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainVm/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" DisplayMemberPath="IntProperty"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.IntProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`BaseVm` реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged`. `WpfApplication4.ViewModels` - пространство имен, в котором расположен класс `MainVm`.

Comment: но коллекцию не видно в xaml'e, пишет, что неизвестный DataContext. Так как у меня три коллекции, я сделал класс Collections, где все эти коллекции - свойства. Я написал  DataContext = coll.MyCollection; но все равно не видно, так же как и свойство класса MyClass
@Vlad

Comment: @NickShepard, я дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Всё просто.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyCollection/Length}"/>
```

Трюк в том, что у коллекции* есть понятие *текущего элемента*. Для того, чтобы при выделении этот текущий элемент обновлялся, нужно `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`. Вы можете в `Binding`'е сослаться на текущий элемент используя `/`. `Length` — то самое интовое свойство.

---

*На самом деле, не у коллекции, а у `CollectionView`, который неявно «надевается» на коллекцию, когда к ней происходит `Binding`.