# Обновление данных в DataGrid

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Главное окно программы содержит `ListBox` с типами оборудования, `dataGrid1` с перечнем оборудования `(Binding к ListBox.SelectedItem)`, `dataGrid2` с историей изменения значений характеристик оборудования(сущность `wrk_Device_ValueLog`).

В окне имеется кнопка "редактировать", при нажатии на которую появляется окно со списком характеристик и значений для выбранного оборудования.
Меняем значения, нажимаем кнопку "сохранить" в этом подчиненном окне и сохраняем контекст(данные сохраняются в таблице `Device`).

В MSSQL на таблице `Device` висит триггер, который записывает данные в таблицу `wrk_Device_ValueLog("Характеристика оборудования", "Имя пользователя", "Дата/Время")`.

Как обновить данные в `dataGrid2` после сохранения данных и закрытия подчиненного окна?

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _dataContext = new DEVICEEntities();
        TypesOfDevice = new ObservableCollection<spr_TypeDevice>
            (_dataContext.spr_TypeDevice.OrderBy(a=>a.Name_TypeDevice));
        Save = new RelayCommand (SaveChanges);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    private void SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            _dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = _mainViewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы делаете как-то неправильно. Вы не должны выставлять в UI модельные классы (сущности базы данных). Об обновлении списков должна заботиться `ViewModel` — например, перечитывать базу. UI должен подхватывать изменения автоматически.

Comment: @VladD, я не выставляю модельные классы во View. В code-behind представления только создаётся контекст со ссылкой на ViewModel. И вот у меня вопрос как перечитывать базу? В ADO.NET у меня был метод GetData с selectом, который я запускал после обновления данных. Как это правильно делается в EF?

Comment: Ну вы вроде выставляете `ObservableCollection<spr_TypeDevice>`, а `spr_TypeDevice` — судя по всему, модельный тип. Но это может быть и не важно в контексте задачи. Смотрите. У вас обновление базы должно быть не напрямую, а через VM, которая список этих элементов выставляет. И тогда эта VM знает, что базу надо обновить, и (1) реально обновляет базу, (2) перечитывает из неё данные, и эти данные через Binding автоматически видны всем. То есть, если я правильно понял ваш код, метод `SaveChanges()` должен обновлять VM-список элементов базы.

Comment: Или если бы `spr_TypeDevice` были VM-элементами, то измененийз в них были бы видны в другом окне автоматически через `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @VladD, да, метод SaveChanges() обновляет таблицу Device (там хранятся все характеристики устройства), а на этой таблице в MSSQL висит триггер, который добавляет данные в таблицу wrk_Device_ValueLog. Так вот изменения в этой таблице как увидеть, как рефрешнуть эту сущность? И кстати, что касается пункта (2) - у меня автоматически не перечитываются данные из таблиц - в окнах, конечно, информация меняется, так как они привязаны к коллекциям, но повторный select к БД не происходит. Может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что обновление окон у вас привязано к чтению базы данных. Это и есть «модельные элементы во view». В качестве костыля, пусть тот код, который вызывает `SaveChanges`, перечитывает данные из таблиц.

Comment: @VladD, пример кода ViewModel и XAML вью можете скинуть? Что-то с трудом понимаю

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что какой именно пример вам нужен, но вот вам код моего тёзки: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477883/10105

Comment: @VladD, спасибо

Comment: Надеюсь, вам подойдёт пример.

Answer (score 1):

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Метод отвечающий за обновление  DataGrid  при внесении изменений
    /// </summary>
    private void RefreshDG()
    {

         DB0.Clear();

         var contractcollection = DB.Contracts.Include("Partner").Include("Respemp").Include("CurrencyOFContract");
        foreach (var item in contractcollection)
        {
            DB0.Add(item);
        }

    }
```

Я писал такой метод и вызывал его после каждого обновления данных в БД.  Или после SaveChages() или после закрытия окна редактирования. Я не могу себя назвать опытным программистом, так что это  решение -  решение новичка. Но DataGrid оно обновляло.  ObservableCollection DB0- ItemSourceдля DataGrid. DB -  DBContext